# rename colorbox popup confirm button

Tags: javascript, dialog, popup, colorbox

I am using colorbox pop up. And on close the confirm box triggers "Are you sure you want to quit?", It shows, Ok and Cancel as default buttons.

My question is can you rename these buttons like "Yes, Close" and "No"

```
var response;
response = confirm('Do you want to close this window? All your changes will not be saved');
if (!response) {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible because these strings are related to the language that you're using in you S.O./Browser. One way is replace the native `confirm()` popup with a modal HTML/JS popup, then you'll get the flexibility that you need.

Example: [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: can i use this within colorbox plugin? cause i tried "dialog('Do you want to close this window? All your changes will not be saved');" its saying dialog not defined. i added the jquery ui scripts

Comment: You can use it anywhere, but you'll need to see the demo page. The code is not so simple, but you'll find all the examples.